# Perform tasks in clojure.core.async channel in parallel

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing

I have a channel for tasks that needs to be performed. I want to perform the tasks in parallel. Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
(pipeline-blocking
  desired-parallelism
  (chan (dropping-buffer 0))
  my-transducer-with-tasks-performed-as-side-effect
  my-task-channel))
```

Although this works, it is incredibly ugly because

1. I need to create a new channel for the sole purpose of dropping items
2. I need to write a transducer when all I care about is the side effects

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Do you need to control the parallelism (like in `pipeline-blocking`)? Or task needs to be performed as soon as it arrives?

Comment: The could be many thousands of tasks so the degree of parallelism needs to be limited.

Comment: Since there's nothing more in `core.async`'s api that allows you to control parallelism apart of `pipeline-*` functions, I would stick with that. Other option is to write your own functions for tasks execution

Comment: Couldn't you just spawn `n` go-routines (where `n` is the desired degree of parallelism) that each read from `my-task-channel` and perform the side-effecting operation?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: You may find that the Claypoole library provides an easier solution for parallel computations instead of core.async.  https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole

Comment: Wow. I have no idea why I never considered multiple go or thread blocks. Seems blindingly obvious now.